# Apollo GraphQL: Why does useMutation in a child component trigger a re-render in the Parent Component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am using '@apollo/client' with react for a social media application. My components are structured as...

MainView.js > PostsView.js > PostCard.js > LikeButton.js

1. MainView.js: has the FETCH_POSTS_QUERY using useQuery

`const { loading, data: { getUsers: users } = {}, error } = useQuery(GET_USERS_QUERY);`

2. LikeButton.js: has the LIKE_POST_MUTATION using useMutation.

`const [likePost] = useMutation(LIKE_POST_MUTATION, { variables: { postId: post.id } })`

MainView fetches the posts and displays the post in a PostCard component which has a LikeButton component, where the like post mutation occurs.

Every time a likePost() is called the PostCard renders and MainView.js (a parent component) rerenders immediately after that, why is that? What is it about the mutation that triggers that MainView.JS component? Also, I have noticed that when I add `fetch-policy: no-cache` to GET_USERS_QUERY, the MainView.js does not rerender. I am not doing anything to the cache in my LIKE_POST_MUTATION, so I am not sure what is the connection there. Also, the rerendering only occurs if likePost is called.

Comment: Give this a read - https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/caching/demystifying-cache-normalization/